# Design Pattern Factory Method question - why the factory method in ConcreteCreator won't be available yet?

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns, factory-method, compiled-language

I am reading *"Design Patterns"* by *Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, John Vlissides*. In chapter of factory method, there's one paragraph:

> "Factory method in C++ are always virtual functions and are often pure
> virtual. Just be careful not to call factory methods in the Creator's
> constructor - the factory method in the ConcreteCreator won't be
> available yet."

I don't understand why the factory method in ConcreteCreator won't be available yet? is it because C++ is a compiled language therefore the method of the children class won't be available as the parent class is compiled first? Thank you.

Comment: `Creator`'s constructor is executing _before_ `ConcreteCreator` has completely come into being. Thus anything that is part of `ConcreteCreator` is not available to `Creator`, including virtual function implementations.

Comment: so that's what happened in run-time when someone called creator right? @jkb

Comment: This is the case when someone instantiates a `ConcreteCreator` object. When that happens, the base class (`Creator`) constructor is invoked first, then `ConcreteCreator`'s. Because of this, you want to be sure that while you're in the `Creator` constructor you don't try to call any virtual functions that might be defined in any derived classes.